# Dual boot with 10.04 and 14.10

Tags: dual-boot, 10.04, 14.10

On a machine with Ubuntu 10.04 is it possible to install Ubuntu 14.10 in a new partition and have a dual boot between the two installations?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Just make new partition for new version of Ubuntu and install it. When you finish your installation and turn on your computer, you'll get a grub screen to choose in what version of Ubuntu do you want to boot.